Truss plate nail orientation
What is the rule for orienting a truss plate's gang-nail slots (horizontal vs vertical)

for where the rafters (i.e. the top chords) meet at the apex

and

for where the top chords abut the bottom chord?

My understanding (from reading about a truss failure) is that the nail slots should be oriented vertically at the apex.
And judging from the picture on a box of code-compliant 6" construction screws (from a major manufacturer) which are designed to fasten the truss through the top plate, the orientation where top chord meets bottom cord is horizontal.   But I'd like to confirm the apex.


Please provide a link to where the image was found. Proper attribution is required by Stack Exchange policies.

@MichaelKaras  It's a photo I took myself of a box of screws, from an area on the back of the box.  I don't think it requires attribution, and I'd prefer not to mention any brand. Suffice to say, as I did say, it is a major manufacturer.  The boxes are readily available on the shelves of most well-stocked home supply stores, and I consider this a "fair use".  There's no proprietary info in the photo and I've seens similar, virtually identical photos used by other manufacturers of similar screws.

The "nail slots" you are referring to are not for nails. they are the result of the manufacturing process that punches out the teeth of the plate.  A special tool is needed to attach the plates.  If you are asking because you are planning to assemble your own trusses, you need the tool or the plates are not the proper for your application., rendering the information moot.

I know they're not for nails. They're the slots created by the punch mechanism that creates the gang nails.  But it's what you can easily see to determine the nail orientation.

There are two ways of installing the truss plate.  Hydraulic press.   Steel compression plates to squeeze the truss plate gang nails into the wood using a heavy duty impact driver to tighten the nuts in a round-robin fashion a bit at a time.  I'm going to use the latter and have already had the plates fabricated. The "nails" need to be seated so there's no more than a 1mm gap between the wood and the plate.  I know you don't hammer the truss plates in with a sledge.
